# Calendar extender missing Month part

Tags: asp.net, textbox, calendarextender

The month part of the calendar is missing.  Please find the code which i am using :

```
                <cc1:CalendarExtender ID="txtfrom_CalendarExtender" runat="server" 
                    Enabled="True" TargetControlID="txtfrom" 
                     >
                </cc1:CalendarExtender>

            <asp:Label ID="Labeldateto" runat="server" Text="To:"></asp:Label>
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtto" runat="server" Display="None" 
                class="Input" Height="16px" Width="136px"></asp:TextBox>


                <cc1:CalendarExtender ID="txtto_CalendarExtender1" runat="server" 
                    Enabled="True" TargetControlID="txtto" 
                    >
                </cc1:CalendarExtender>

        </td>
```

I am getting output like
[image: Month part is missing]

Please advice!!

Comment: I used all the default setting.

Answer (score 0):

please find the correct code to solve mention issue.[image]